# Move window to activity from shell in Plasma 5

Tags: kde, plasma, kde5, plasma5

I am trying to set a window's activity from a terminal or script. I know you can assign all these attributes from the System Settings, but I need to do it from a script. I know you can set the display with `env DISPLAY=:0 <command>` but assigning a window to an activity and printing it's environment variables don't show anything. I looked through the `qdbus` tab complete stuff for activity manager and kwin but didn't find anything about setting the activity. Does anybody know how to do this or is it even possible?

Comment: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=271686

Comment: If you can do something with your keyboard and mouse, you should be able to get AutoKey to do it for you by pressing a hotkey that runs a script. I probably won't tackle this on my own, but if anyone is interested in working on it, I'd be gad to help. Come and discuss it at https://gitter.im/autokey/autokey.